# I can't figure out the difference in a method

Tags: objective-c, class

```
@interface Rectangle: NSObject
-(void) setOrigin : (XYPoint *) pt;
-(XYPoint *) origin;
...
@end

#import "XYPoint.h"
#import "Rectangle.h"
@implementation Rectangle
-(void) setOrigin : (XYPoint *) pt
{
   origin = pt;
}

-(XYPoint *) origin 
{
   return origin;
}
@end

@interface XYPoint: NSObject
@property int x, y;
-(void) setX: (int) xVall andY; (int) yVal;
@end

#import "XYPoint.h"
@implementation XYPoint
@synthesize x, y
-(void) setX: (int) xVal andY: (int) yVal
{
   x = xVal;
   y = yVal;
}
@end
```

Above is part of the classes.
This is main

```
int main (int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    XYPoint* myPoint = [[XYPoint alloc]init];
    Rectangle* myRect = [[Rectangle alloc]init];

    [myPoint setX: 200 andY: 100];

    [myRect setOrigin: myPoint];
    NSLog(@"origin of rectangle: (%i, %i)", myRect.origin.x, myRect.origin.y);
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine as I expected. But, if I change the method

```
setOrigin: (XYPoint *) pt
```

in Rectangle class, to

```
-(void) setOrigin: (XYPoint *) pt
{
    origin.x = pt.x;
    origin.y = pt.y;
}
```

it just prints the value of 0 for both x and y. What is the difference between these two method. For me, it seems the same.

Comment: Can you provide the `@interface` for `XYPoint` and `Rectangle` too?

Answer (score 2):

I bet you don't `alloc` and `init` your `origin` object in the initialization of the `Rectangle` class...

Comment: @ProgrammingNerd In what sense? Do you alloc-init or not? If not, do so.

Comment: Then in the first one, why does it work without doing alloc-init on the object?

Comment: @ProgrammingNerd Because in the first one, you **are** alloc-initting it, just not within the class. Learn C before trying to get into Objective-C, apparently you have no idea how pointers work.

Comment: @ProgrammingNerd In the first case, you assign the whole object so `origin` now points to a valid `XYPoint` object. In the second, your code assumes there is already a valid object in place and you update its two properties to new values. If `origin` is `nil`, this won't work.

Comment: @H2CO3 I know your smart and all that, but every time you comment on my question, it is annoying and condescending. I am currently learning C and I'm just asking this because the explanation on the book that I'm reading wasn't enough. If you're going to be mean, just don't help. I don't need yours anyway.

Comment: @ProgrammingNerd You need to learn C. There's no excuse. Look at how many people *didn't need* to ask questions like this.

Comment: @H2CO3 Well, asking questions is not bad, is it? and I told you I'm learning C.

Comment: @ProgrammingNerd I don't want to continue this pointless discussion - you didn't understand my point. Let's stop this here and now.